# hang when make_request calls submit_bio

Tags: kernel, device, block

I am writing a stacking block device driver in 2.6.32 kernel. We need to create a new bio and call submit_bio in make_request before redirecting the bio from request queue to lower devices. For this we made a function my_sync_io() that is similar to sync_page_io() from md.

However, our function, my_sync_io() never returns. After 120 seconds, kernel panic. 
We think the function is waiting something such as lock.

Any one knows about this ?

Thanks.